# How to add Lat/long columns to a point layer which is not in WGS84?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, centroids

I need to extract the Lat/long coordinates of the centroids of districts.
My QGIS project SCR and the different layers have all been set on "WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N".

I've created the centroids using the usual tool.
I could then extracted the coordinates using the "Vector > Geometry Tools > Export/Add Geometry Columns", or saving the layer in CSV typing "GEOMETRY=AS_XY" in the "Layers" part of the "OGR creation options".

Nevertheless, both methods output Cartesian coordinates, whereas I need Lat/long coordinates.